# Inverse Laplace Transform of something of kind $s^nF(s)$

Tags: solution-verification, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Is it correct to say that, if $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=F(s)$, I have

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{s^{n}F(s)\}=f^{(n)}(t)+c\delta(t),$$

where $c=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f^{(k)}(0)$?

I think as follows:
$$\mathcal{L}\{f^{(n)}(t)+c\delta(t)\}=(s^{n}F(s)-c)+c\cdot 1=s^{n}F(s).$$

But I am not sure.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression for $c$ in the OP is incorrect.  In fact, $c$ depends on $s$, the transform variable.  Specifically, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} \{f^{(n)}\} &=s^n F(s)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s^kf^{(n-1-k)}(0)\\\\
&=s^nF(s)-c(s)
\end{align}$$

where $c(s)$ is given by

$$c(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s^kf^{(n-1-k)}(0)$$

Therefore, the inverse Laplace transform of $s^nF(s)$ is

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{s^nF(s)\}(t)&=f^{(n)}(t)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f^{(n-1-k)}(0)\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{s^k\}(t)\\\\
&=f^{(n)}(t)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f^{(n-1-k)}(0)\delta^{(k)}(t)
\end{align}$$

where $\delta^{(k)}(t)$ is the $k$'th order distributional derivative of the Dirac Delta.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much once again!

Comment: @Na'omi You're welcome as always.